# async post call in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, asynchronous, rest-client

i have a project on python 2.7. i need to make async post call to connect aws. i have an code for async in python 3.5 by using asyncio.but my code needs to work on python2.7 2.7.please guide me how to resolve this issue.

```
import asyncio
import json
from aiohttp import ClientSession
HEADERS = {'Content-type':'application/json'}
async def hello(url):
    data = {"mac": 'mm','minor':3,'distance':1,'timestamp':4444,'uuid':'aa','rssi':1,'tx':34}    
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(url,json=data) as response:
            response = await response.read()
            print(response)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
url = "http://192.168.101.74:9090/api/postreader"
while True:
    loop.run_until_complete(hello(url))
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation, it's really helpful. Python2.7 lacks `async` keywords, so you need to rewrite your code in some other manner, possibly with other framework (e.g. Tornado)

Answer (score 1):

Try using gevent instead of asyncio?

http://www.gevent.org/

https://pypi.org/project/gevent/#downloads